# oracle database link for data replication, resources and perfomance

Tags: database, oracle, hyperlink, replication

Environment used: two Oracle 12c databases (productive and development/testing). To replicate data of some particular tables on demand from prod to dev, we plan to use a database link. Some tables are relatively big ~1G, so its is not clear on which database the link should be created to have a minimal impact to transactions/performance on production? Or does it make any difference at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move data around, consider using a tool which is designed for that - **Data Pump**. Export data from the production database and import it into development. It works at the operating system level, but user - that performs that operation - should have access to *directory* (Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory, place where export file (DMP) and log file are located).

Database link presumes that you know login credentials of the "target" database. So, if you create a database link from development to production, you'd *pull* data to development database. However, there's a risk that developers will be able to *destroy* production data (delete tables, truncate them, update values, ... anything they want). So, that's not exactly "performance" problem but *security issue*.

Vice versa? Production should *push* data to development.

Once again: I'd use [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-17FAE261-0972-4220-A2E4-44D479F519D4).